# How to induce SwingWorker error

Tags: java, swing, junit

I want to write JUnit test to my `SwingWorker` derivative class. In `done()` function I have

```
if (status.getStatusCode() == Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.getStatusCode())
```

statement. How I can cover this condition? How to induce SwingWorker server error or mock get status?

Answer (score 4):

For your code to be testable without resorting to hackish tricks, you should separate the concerns of "being a `SwingWorker`" and doing the actual business logic.

Have a `SwingWorker` that takes a `Runnable` or similar and have a separate class implement the `Runnable` so you can instantiate that and test it independently.